# Javascript and JSP for 2 buttons with submit

Tags: javascript, jsp, submit

Not a real into javascript yet, hoping you could help me out with this possible newbee question.
I'm trying to expand an existing working jsp page with a second button. It's type is submit.
I found some semi simular questions and answers , but I just don't get it working.
The button I added for this example is the button.doebi. They come well on screen in the browser.

Inside my jsp file :

```
<td colspan="4" align="right">
    <button id="sysBlaBlacControlSearchSubmit" type="submit" value="normal" class="standardButton">
        <bean:message key="button.search" />
    </button>
    <button id="sysBlaBlaControlSearchReset" type="reset" class="standardButton">
        <bean:message key="button.reset" />
    </button>
    <button id="sysBlaBlaControlSearchDoebi" type="submit" name="doebi" value="doebi" class="standardButton">
        <bean:message key="button.doebi" />
    </button>
</td>
```

Inside my js file :

```
$('#SysBlaBlaControlSearchForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sendAjaxForm('SysBlaBlaSearch', '/sysblabla/sysBlaBlaSearch.do', 'searchSysblabla', function (result) {
            refreshTableData(systematicControlSearchResultTable, result);

            sendAjaxGET('/blablabla/blablabla.do', 'getblablablaSearchWarning', undefined, function (result) {
                $('div#SysBlaBlaBlaSearchWarning').text(result.value);
            });

        });
    });
```

Now I want to see witch button has been pressed, because obviosly both buttons are processed in the .submit

In found examples over here like `if (request.getParameter("xxx"))` with I like to inject in my code like this in the js file :

```
$('#SysBlaBlaControlSearchForm').submit(function(e) {
        if (request.getParameter("doebi") == null) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.warn("NOT inside doebi click");
        sendAjaxForm('SysBlaBlaSearch', '/sysblabla/sysBlaBlaSearch.do', 'searchSysblabla', function (result) {
        ...
    } else {
        console.warn("inside doebi click");
    }
```

but the problem is the "request" is not found by the compiler.
I don't know where the request is pointing to.

When I execute the code in the browser and do inspect I got a error on the request.
I had to camouflage the real methode names with blabla, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `click` event to get the current button clicked and then on `submit` you can checked which button was clicked and perform further operation related to that button.

**Demo code** :

```js
var $submit = null;
var $button = $('#SysBlaBlaControlSearchForm').find('button');
$('#SysBlaBlaControlSearchForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //checking the value of button click
  if ($submit.name == "normal") {
    //normal buton is clicked
    console.warn(" inside normal click");
    //put your ajax code here

  } else if ($submit.name == "doebi") {
    //inside doebii
    console.warn("inside doebi click");
    //put your ajax code here
  } else {
    console.warn("reset button clicked");
  }


});
//when button is clicked
$button.click(function(event) {
  //putting current button clicked reference in variable $submit
  $submit = this;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="SysBlaBlaControlSearchForm">
  <button id="sysBlaBlacControlSearchSubmit" type="submit" name="normal" class="standardButton">
        <bean:message key="button.search" />Normal
    </button>
  <button id="sysBlaBlaControlSearchReset" type="reset" class="standardButton">
        <bean:message key="button.reset" /> Reset
    </button>
  <button id="sysBlaBlaControlSearchDoebi" type="submit" name="doebi" namename="doebi" class="standardButton">
        <bean:message key="button.doebi" />Doebi
    </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Hey, it works, thanks a lot. It also helped me to understand the flow of submit better.